# Disable upgrade-insecure-requests

Tags: java, html

I am facing a issue with CORS and Upgrade-insecure-request headers. I am trying to provide CORS support to my project. Also, I have set minimum restriction of "x-frame-options:same-origin" so that any client/customer who tries to frame my app without making CORS request will fail to do so.

In order to test it I have a test page that makes CORS request and loads my app into an iframe. Now when I try to navigate my app, by clicking on a tab, the new page fails to load and can see that the browser throws "same-origin" policy error.

Analyzing the network traffic, shows that, when the tab was clicked first a "http" request was made with upgrade-insecure as one of the headers. then the response has location header with "http" only (not https because my app does not process this header yet). When the browser redirects to the page in the location header, then the CORS headers ("origin") is not present in the request and browser then sees the same-origin policy and hence the iframe fails to load the page.

I came across a mozilla issue, which mentions that the presence of upgrade-insecure header will stop the CORS. But I have not enabled this header any where in my app either through web-server or using meta-data. Then how is the browser adding this header? I have been looking at disabling this header but am not successful till now.

I have been following https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/#upgrade-request this page in order to understand in what scenarios is this header getting added.

> sec 3:Upgrading Insecure Resource Requests "Environment settings objects and browsing contexts are given an insecure requests policy which has two potential values Do Not Upgrade and Upgrade. It is set to Do Not Upgrade unless otherwise specified.".

It is mentioned that the default policy is "Do Not Upgrade". But I am not sure how this header is present then? 
In short could you please help me in disabling this header.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code and create a [mcve]

Comment: over discribing your issue is not good habit,